# How can i select multiple network interface using apache httpclient 4.1.2

Tags: java, apache, httpclient, network-interface

I have multiple network interface(Like WIFI,LAN,LTE dougle).I am sending http request using apache httpclient 4.1.2. I want to select the network interface during  sending the http request. I can see the network interfaces using  java.net.NetworkInterface class. Can anyone help me how can i do it using http client? I want to send one http request using one network interface and second http request using the other interface. Its like load balancing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the ConnRoutePNames.LOCAL_ADDRESS='http.route.local-address' parameter to the INetAddress of the desired interface. See [section 2.4](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html) of this doc for more information.